# GSSAPI ssh login on Ubuntu 14.04 with SSSD and Active Directory

Tags: 14.04, ssh, active-directory, kerberos

I'm trying to move from 12.04LTS with likewise-open to 14.04LTS with sssd using realmd and I've got it working for the most part, but I can't get Kerberos SSO to work. Under likewise I was able to do an ssh from my Mac to the Ubuntu box as long as I had a kerberos ticket from Active Directory. But under sssd gssapi-with-mic just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. In order to get it to work I had to:

1. Make sure the default_realm is set in `/etc/krb5.conf`
2. log in as `DOMAIN\username` where `DOMAIN` is the short NETBIOS version of the domain name in all caps.

Other variations of the domain name worked with a password, but not with a `kerberos` ticket and `GSSAPI`.

Upon further research, it seems like this is related to auth_to_local and pam mappings in /etc/krb5.conf that were left over from likewise-open.

Comment: Please consider marking your own answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left so that this issue can be marked as solved..